# How to create calendar table with end of each month only SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What would be the simplest way to create a calendar table or CTE that would return end of each month date of the year?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Which / how many years do you want to generate it for?

Comment: would be nice to be able to supply date range. But I would say 5 years

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps not the simplest, but the most *efficient* way is with a tally:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --Add more for more months
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, '20000101') AS MonthStart,
       EOMOMTH(DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, '20000101')) AS MonthEnd 
FROM Tally T;
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. But can it be modified to generate End of month? Not the beginning?

Comment: I guess I can just add EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, '20000101'))

Comment: You can use `TOP (N)` in the `SELECT ROW_NUMBER()...` statement, @Serdia and/or change the number of times `N` is referenced in `Tally`.

Comment: if you don't have SQL 2017 then replace the EOMOMTH function with ,(DATEADD(MONTH, T.I,DATEADD(month,1,DATEADD(day,-1, '20000101')))) AS MonthEnd

Comment: @KeithL you don't need SQL Server 2017 for `EOMONTH`, just a **supported** version.

Answer (score 2):

The EOMONTH function will work in this case, see the last field in the query below.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01/01/2015' 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '12/01/2016' 

;WITH OrderedDays as 
( 
    SELECT CalendarDate = @StartDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CalendarDate)
    FROM OrderedDays WHERE DATEADD (MONTH, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate 
),
Calendar AS
(
    SELECT
        EndOfMonth =  EOMONTH ( CalendarDate ) 
    FROM
        OrderedDays                 
) 
SELECT * FROM Calendar
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: `;` goes at the end of your statement, not before a `WITH`. It's a statement terminator, not a "beginningator" ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tidbit! Old habits die hard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive common table expression for this:

```
with cte as (
    select cast('2018-01-31' as date) EndOfMonth
    union all
    select eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, EndOfMonth)) 
    from cte 
    where EndOfMonth < cast('2018-12-01' as date)
)
select * from cte
```

The anchor member starts on the last day of January 2018, and the recursive member adds 1 month per iteration, using `eomonth()` to always return the last day of the month, until December 2018 is reached. You can easily adjust the start and end date as needed.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bfe9fda9414cdf4ac3c945464ee6953)**

```
| EndOfMonth          |
| :------------------ |
| 31/01/2018 00:00:00 |
| 28/02/2018 00:00:00 |
| 31/03/2018 00:00:00 |
| 30/04/2018 00:00:00 |
| 31/05/2018 00:00:00 |
| 30/06/2018 00:00:00 |
| 31/07/2018 00:00:00 |
| 31/08/2018 00:00:00 |
| 30/09/2018 00:00:00 |
| 31/10/2018 00:00:00 |
| 30/11/2018 00:00:00 |
| 31/12/2018 00:00:00 |
```

**Edit**

As commented by @squillman: if you plan to generate more than 7 years of calendar, then you need to add clause `option(maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

As commented by @Larnu: performance of recursive query does degrades when the dataset becomes bigger. If you need to generate a very large calendar (like several centuries), then other options are better.

Finally: if you find yourself repeatively generating calendar tables in your queries, then you should consider *materializing* the calendar, ie storing it in a real database table, that you can then `join` in your queries. This is a widely used solution in database design that makes queries simpler and more efficient. You can use of the suggested queries to initially feed the table.

Comment: Note, this will get slow(er) with larger data sets. rCTEs, as their name suggest, are recursive, and SQL Server does not excel at iterative tasks

Comment: +1 with the caveat that you can't get more than a little over 7 years without hitting the max recursion depth (for SQL Server 2017 anyway).

Comment: When you say larger data sets, how many years you think dataset should be to notice slow performance?

Comment: @Larnu: yes I do agree, on a large dataset performance will suffer. But for a small on like here, I find the the simplicity and brievity of the recursive query overcomes the tiny performance difference.

Comment: @Serdia: it depends on your performance requirement... As a guess: up to a few hundreds or maybe a thousand of iterations I would not expect a noticeable difference. This query does just 12 iterations per year so that gives you room (up to a few centuries). You would need to test for real in your database. Larnu please feel free to comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

U can use a master..spt_values system table. Here's a piece of sample code:

```
SELECT    DATEADD([dd], -1, DATEFROMPARTS(2020, [number] + 1, 1))
    FROM  master..spt_values
    WHERE [number] BETWEEN 1 AND 11
          AND [type] = 'P'
UNION
SELECT dateadd(dd, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(2021, 1, 1))
```

EDIT: OK, thx to @Ross Bush, there is a better and smaller code:

```
SELECT    EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(2020, [number], 1))
    FROM  master..spt_values
    WHERE [number] BETWEEN 1 AND 12
          AND [type] = 'P'
```

Answer (score 1):

I enriched a bit this answer found in different forums, and used to create a Calendar Table for my DWH.

`

```
DECLARE @StartDate  date = '20000101';
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, 50, @StartDate));
;WITH seq(n) AS 

(

SELECT 0 UNION ALL 
SELECT n + 1 
FROM seq
WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)
),
d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @StartDate) FROM seq
),
src AS
(
  SELECT
    TheDate         = CONVERT(date, d),
    DateAsInteger   = CONVERT(INT, format(d,'yyyyMMdd')),
    TheDay          = DATEPART(DAY,       d),
    TheDayName      = DATENAME(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheWeek         = DATEPART(WEEK,      d),
    TheISOWeek      = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,  d),
    TheDayOfWeek    = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,   d),
    TheMonth        = DATEPART(MONTH,     d),
    TheMonthName    = DATENAME(MONTH,     d),
    TheQuarter      = DATEPART(Quarter,   d),
    TheYear         = DATEPART(YEAR,      d),
    YearMonthnumber = CONVERT(INT, format(d,'yyyyMM')),
    YearMonthShort  = format(d,'yyyy-MMM'),
    TheFirstOfMonth = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), MONTH(d), 1),
    TheLASTOfMonth  = EOMONTH(d),
    TheLastOfYear   = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(d), 12, 31),
    TheDayOfYear    = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, d)
  FROM d
)
SELECT * into AN_Calendar  FROM src
  ORDER BY TheDate
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);`
```

It should answer your question and a few others.